# How to run two instances of the same app for two Kinects?

Tags: vb.net, kinect

I want to ask is there any way to check whether a Kinect is being used at the moment (sensor.start) so that we can use another Kinect for another application or in the same application? I tried using Kinect.IsRunning but it's not working.

Here is the case: I have an application that runs on one Kinect, but I want to run this application two times. I have two Kinects connected to my PC. The problem is whenever I ran the second application, it will detect the same Kinect to be used causing the second application to crash. I want this application can know if the first Kinect sensor already start, it will go for the next one. I have read this article but it doesn't help me to solve this problem. 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e8e96d97-ec02-430e-b80c-a40ae6b92604/running-two-instances-of-the-same-app-for-two-kinects?forum=kinectsdknuiapi

So far I hard-coded the Kinect ID into my application, but that means I need to have two applications which is not efficient. If I need to change the Kinect I need to change the ID again inside the codes. Anyone can help me. please? I thought it should be not difficult, but I still haven't found any function to do that. I'm writing my codes in VB.Net

Comment: There is a sample code (MultiDepthViewer) for this in a standard package - OpenNI2. https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI2/tree/master/Samples/MultiDepthViewer . The side effect though is that each Kinect camera makes its own IR pattern and when they overlap the depth image becomes noisy. For example you can see little bumps protruding from the wall.

Comment: thanks! I will look through it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
For Each _sensor As KinectSensor In KinectSensor.KinectSensors
    sensor = _sensor

    ...//setup event handlers and such

    Try
        sensor.Start() //If it gets past this, then we can exit as it has
                       // successfully started a kinect
        Exit For

    Catch ex As ApplicationException
        MsgBox("That Kinect is being used in another application, moving to the next")
    Catch ex2 As IOException
        MsgBox("Error")
    End Try
Next
```

This will search all the kinects, try to start them, and if an `ApplicationException` is thrown, then it moves onto the next kinect.

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer! the syntax was okay except for the Exit. by Exit do you mean exit the loop or exit the try?  I tried to exit the try at first, it becomes the chosen Kinect will always the second Kinect. So, I tried to exit the for loop inside the try, but it only check the first Kinect, so in the end I still unable to make it shift to the next Kinect. At least the crash is gone. Just that the second application cannot activate the other Kinect so it is just showing nothing.

Comment: @user3423299 It should exit the loop after it finds a valid kinect. Sorry that my code is sloppy but it should loop through the kinects, try to start one, if it fails, then it goes onto the next kinect, and if it succeeds then it should exit the loop

Comment: @user342399 Also are you sure that the loop goes through every kinect? Place a breakpoint to see if it goes through the loop multiple times

Comment: your code is alright :) yeap~ it can loop through all the Kinects. The problem is because we put the "Exit For" inside the try. So, it will try to exit the forloop every time :( I tried to put exit try above the exit for, but ended up it will exit the try which cause the app to continue the loop (because exit for is inside the Try). So, in the end, eventhough it is failed to start the sensor, it will still exit the forloop causing the second app showing nothing. any suggestion?

Comment: wow! it works great! thanks a lot @Outlaw Lemur . so we have to catch the IOException too. I get it now :D

Comment: @user3423299 No problem... I initially thought that it was unneeded because in my C# code I don't have one, but then I tested it with VB and it made the difference